# hector scala type mismatch

Tags: scala, hector

What could be wrong?

```
val is = IntegerSerializer.get
mutator.addInsertion(deviceId, COLUMN_FAMILY_CARSTATUS, createColumn("mileage", 111, ss, is))}


ModelOperation.scala:96: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.IntegerSerializer
[INFO]  required: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer[Any]
[INFO] Note: java.lang.Integer <: Any (and me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.IntegerSerializer <: me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.AbstractSerializer[java.lang.Integer]), but Java-defined trait Serializer is invariant in type T.
[INFO] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[INFO]      mutator.addInsertion(deviceId, COLUMN_FAMILY_CARSTATUS, createColumn("mileage", 111, ss, is))}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is saying that `createColumn` requires a serializer of type `Serializer[Any]`, but you're passing one of type `Serializer[Integer]`. This would only work if `Serializer` were covariant in its type parameter (i.e., defined as `Serializer[+T]`). But instead, `Serializer` comes from Java, where covariance works differently.

The type `Serializer[Integer]` can be safely cast to `Serializer[_ <: Any]`, so the Scala compiler is suggesting that maybe `createColumn` should have been written to expect that less specific wildcard type instead.

If you can't modify `createColumn`, then a last resort is to use the "type system escape hatch" `asInstanceOf` to cast to the expected type:

```
val is = IntegerSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[Any]] // defeats type system
mutator.addInsertion(... is ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your workaround doesn't work. For this code:
`val a = createColumn("updateTime", 11, ss, IntegerSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[_ <: Any]])`

I'm getting this error:
`error: type mismatch;
found   : me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer[_$2] where type _$2
required: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer[Any]
Note: _$2 <: Any, but Java-defined trait Serializer is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as \`_ <: Any\`. (SLS 3.2.10)
val a = createColumn("updateTime", 11, ss, IntegerSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[_ <: Any]])`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I couldn't test it. How about just casting to `Serializer[Any]`? I updated the answer.

Comment: By the way, here is the relevant Java code: https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/serializers/IntegerSerializer.java

Comment: It worked, thanks!
`createColumn("mileage", 11, ss, IntegerSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[Any]])`
compiles just fine.

Comment: what about LongSerializer.. the same problem occurs using LongSerializer.